# using variables and percent values to position an item on a page

Tags: css, sass

let's say I have an element like so.

```
$div1-height: height(icon);
.div1 {
  left: 0;
  top: 25%;
  height: $div1-height; 
}
```

then I have another div somewhere, and I want to use the position to mathematically position it on the screen. Conceptually, I want to do this.

```
.div2 {
  top: 25% + $div1-height;
}
```

Is such a thing possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25% is evaluated at run time, so it wont work to calculate it before the page is rendered. You can use calc though, like this

```
top: calc(25% + #{$div1-height});
```

But it may not have the greatest browser support. I would consider re-working some of your other css, so you don't have to use calc.

Comment: where would it not be supported?

Comment: [It has decent support actually:](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) 72.94%. The main sticking point would be ie8 and older android.

Comment: so here be a problem; when I use `top: calc(25% + 10px);`, it works plenty fine. But when I do `top: calc(25% + $var);` it will say "invalid property value". I logged the value of $var in a CSS rule called val, and it came out to 121px. what's going on?

Comment: [Check out this issue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/818). You need to use it like calc(100% + #{$var})